# Using Jenkins parameters in python script

Tags: python, variables, jenkins

How can I use parameters from my Jenkins job in the python script? I will mention that python script is run in bash shell and Jenkins job is multi-configuration project not pipeline

I try to use parameter REPO_PATH (= gramar/repo) from Jenkins job in my python script but it doesn't work:

```
import json
import os

PATH = os.environ.get('REPO_PATH')

json_text = str()
with open ('PATH/file.json','r') as f:
json_text = f.read()

data = json.loads(json_text)
```

I can see:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "script.py", line 9, in

with open 'PATH/file.json', 'r') as f:
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:'PATH/file.json'

Answer (score 0):

You have a error in your code:

```
import json
import os

PATH = os.environ.get('REPO_PATH')

json_text = str()
with open (f'{PATH}/file.json','r') as f:
   json_text = f.read()
data = json.loads(json_text)
```